# Redirecting stdout from multiple processes to python Logging module

Tags: python, redirect, subprocess, stdout, popen

I have a python script that launches a number of user processes using subprocess.Popen. Each process stdout is redirected to a unique file. For example the I launch each process as follows

```
proc = my_proc  
for p in range(1, max_p, 1):  
    log_file = proc + "_" + str(p) + ".log"  
    log = open(log_file, "w+")  
    subprocess.Popen([my_proc, p], shell = False, stdout = log)
```

I would like to rotate these files when they become too big. What would the best way of doing this? I would like to use the logging module but I dont think this is its intended use

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not a pythonic solution; but on linux systems I prefer using logrotate to automatically rotate my logs.  Check to see if its installed on your system (On ubuntu say there is a directory called /etc/logrotate.d/ with files automatically run via cron).  This may or may not be preferred to having log rotation run from within the application.

It's very configurable, e.g., allows compression of older files keeps N files via rotate N command, rotates when the cron over "size 100k", and looking at man logrotate, its very straightforward to setup.

From the man page here's a sample file

```
   # sample logrotate configuration file
   compress

   /var/log/messages {
       rotate 5
       weekly
       postrotate
           /usr/bin/killall -HUP syslogd
       endscript
   }

   "/var/log/httpd/access.log" /var/log/httpd/error.log {
       rotate 5
       mail www@my.org
       size 100k
       sharedscripts
       postrotate
           /usr/bin/killall -HUP httpd
       endscript
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, however ther may be upto 100 processes launched from the python script. Would I need an entry for each process and logfile ?

Comment: You do not need entries for every process/logfile -- it supports wildcards.  E.g., if all your logs are stored in a directory /var/log/some_app/*.log can be used to rotate all the log files in that directory.  This is actually the third example, that I cut off.

Answer (score 0):

How about `logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler`?

Comment: Thanks, but I need a logger for each process. Is that possible with this class?

Comment: It should be possible if you have an id for each process - then you can bake the id into the filename.